# Why is my code not displaying these 2 Arraylists?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I need to display an ArrayList with a list of college degree/s that an individual may have.

In another ArrayList, I need display the list of individual/s that meet the requirement of college degree that a company is asking.

Tried a system.out inside the loops and it's not even accessing the for loops.

*The 2 methods with the for loops are at the end of this class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecruitingCompany {


private String companyName;
private int phoneNumber;
private String address;
private ArrayList<CollegeDegree> collegeDegreeList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();

private Candidate candidate;
private Requirement academicDegree;

public RecruitingCompany(){
    /*main constructor*/
}


public RecruitingCompany(String companyName, int phoneNumber, String address){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public int getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public ArrayList<CollegeDegree> getCollegeDegreeList() {
    return collegeDegreeList;
}

public void setCollegeDegreeList(ArrayList<CollegeDegree> collegeDegreeList) {
    this.collegeDegreeList = collegeDegreeList;
}

public ArrayList<Candidate> getCandidateList() {
    return candidateList;
}

public void setCandidateList(ArrayList<Candidate> candidateList) {
    this.candidateList = candidateList;
}

public Candidate getCandidate() {
    return candidate;
}

public void setCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    this.candidate = candidate;
}

public Requirement getAcademicDegree() {
    return academicDegree;
}

public void setAcademicDegree(Requirement academicDegree) {
    this.academicDegree = academicDegree;
}

public String showCandidateCollegeDegrees(){
    String degree = "Candidato: " + candidate.getName() + "\n";

    for (CollegeDegree cd: this.collegeDegreeList){
        degree += cd.toString();
    }
    return degree;
}

public String selectByCollegeDegree(){
    String person = "Título: " + academicDegree.getDegree() + "\n";

    for (Candidate c: this.candidateList){
            person += c.toString();
    }
    return person;
}

}
```

The Tester class

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AvailableJob availableJob = new AvailableJob(2005, 2011, "Contador", 444464444, "Metalco", "del poste de luz, 50m oeste", 550.000);
    Candidate candidate = new Candidate("Asdrubal", 888888888, "Asdrubal@yahoo.com", "Bachillerato"); 
    CollegeDegree collegeDegree = new CollegeDegree("Bachillerato Administracion", 2003, "Universidad Aguila Calva");
    RecruitingCompany recruitingCo = new RecruitingCompany();
    Requirement requirement = new Requirement("Bachillerato", 4);

    recruitingCo.setCandidate(candidate); 
    recruitingCo.setAcademicDegree(requirement); 
    availableJob.setRequirement(requirement);

    System.out.println(recruitingCo.showCandidateCollegeDegrees());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(recruitingCo.selectByCollegeDegree());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(availableJob.showRequirement());

    //System.out.print(recruitingCo.getCandidateList());
}

}
```

Comment: You never add anything to those `ArrayList`s.

Comment: How so? I'm adding them in the Tester.

Comment: You're setting the fields `candidate`and `academicDegree`, but those don't modify the `List`s. If you want to, you need to call the `add` method on the lists (e.g. inside of your `setCandidate` method).

Comment: OK, now I see why. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the new candidate or degree to the arraylists. Change the following methods it will work,

```
public void setAcademicDegree(Requirement academicDegree) {
    this.academicDegree = academicDegree;
    collegeDegreeList.add(academicDegree);
}
```

and

```
public void setCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    this.candidate = candidate;
    candidateList.add(candidate);
}
```

Now when you set a new Candidate object or CollegeDegree object it will be automatically added to the lists.

Comment: Yes this worked. I wasn't adding anything to the lists as resueman said in another post. I made some other changes to make everything work but this post put me on track. Thanks

Comment: No problem, thanks for your acknowledgement though... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to do some changes:

1. `setCollegeDegreeList()`, `setCandidateList()` and `setCandidate()` methods
   should be changed to `addCollegDegree()` and `addCandidate()`
2. `recruitingCo.setCandidate(candidate)` should be replaced to
   `recruitingCo.addCandidate(candidate);`
3. Need to add `recruitingCo.addCollegeDegree(collegeDegree);` in main();

And you can get following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecruitingCompany {


private String companyName;
private int phoneNumber;
private String address;
private ArrayList<CollegeDegree> collegeDegreeList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<>();   
private Requirement academicDegree;

public RecruitingCompany(){
    /*main constructor*/
}


public RecruitingCompany(String companyName, int phoneNumber, String address){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public int getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public ArrayList<CollegeDegree> getCollegeDegreeList() {
    return collegeDegreeList;
}

public ArrayList<Candidate> getCandidateList() {
    return candidateList;
}

public void addCollegeDegree(CollegeDegree collegeDegree) {
    this.collegeDegreeList.add(collegeDegree);
}

public void addCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    this.candidateList.add(candidate);
}

public Requirement getAcademicDegree() {
    return academicDegree;
}

public void setAcademicDegree(Requirement academicDegree) {
    this.academicDegree = academicDegree;
}

public String showCandidateCollegeDegrees(){
    String degree = "Candidato: " + candidate.getName() + "\n";

    for (CollegeDegree cd: this.collegeDegreeList){
        degree += cd.toString();
    }
    return degree;
}

public String selectByCollegeDegree(){
    String person = "Título: " + academicDegree.getDegree() + "\n";

    for (Candidate c: this.candidateList){
            person += c.toString();
    }
    return person;
}

}
```

**Tester:**

```
public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AvailableJob availableJob = new AvailableJob(2005, 2011, "Contador", 444464444, "Metalco", "del poste de luz, 50m oeste", 550.000);
    Candidate candidate = new Candidate("Asdrubal", 888888888, "Asdrubal@yahoo.com", "Bachillerato"); 
    CollegeDegree collegeDegree = new CollegeDegree("Bachillerato Administracion", 2003, "Universidad Aguila Calva");
    RecruitingCompany recruitingCo = new RecruitingCompany();
    Requirement requirement = new Requirement("Bachillerato", 4);

    recruitingCo.addCandidate(candidate); 
    recruitingCo.addСollegeDegree(collegeDegree); 

    recruitingCo.setAcademicDegree(requirement); 
    availableJob.setRequirement(requirement);

    System.out.println(recruitingCo.showCandidateCollegeDegrees());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(recruitingCo.selectByCollegeDegree());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(availableJob.showRequirement());

    //System.out.print(recruitingCo.getCandidateList());
}

}
```

Comment: Code dump answers are not useful because it is not clear what you have actually changed. Please describe what the changes are. Also, it is rarely useful to replicate code which you haven't changed - if it's not part of the problem, don't make it part of the answer.

Comment: He added 2 lines in the tester class.